Switching LTE bands in DWM-222
In the modem DWM-222 HW Ver. A1 with firmware 1.9.2 installed, I was able to force LTE bands through AT commands
ati
Manufacturer: 
Model: +CGMM: LTE WIRELESS MODEM
Revision: 1.9.2
IMEI: xxxxxxxxxxx6800
+GCAP: +CGSM

OK
at+bmmodpref
+BMMODPREF: 41

OK
at+bmbandpref=?
+BMBANDPREF: support band: 0x2000000680380, 0x80045, 0x31 

OK
at+bmbandpref?
+BMBANDPREF: 0x2000000680380, 0x80045, 0x3F

OK
at+bmmodpref=0
+BMMODPREF: 0

OK
at+bmmodpref
+BMMODPREF: 0

OK
===================
===================
Only LTE:
at+bmmodpref=7
+BMMODPREF: 7

OK
at+bmrat
+BMRAT: LTE

OK
===================
Band1 (2100 MHz):
at+bmbandpref=2000000680380,1,3f


OK
at+bmtcellinfo
+BMTCELLINFO: CELL_ID:111925783,111925783,LAC_ID:65535,RSSI:71, RSRP:-105, RSRQ:-17, SINR:-94,active band:1,active channel:0,EARFCN_DL:0,EARFCN_UL:0

OK
at+bmband
+BMBAND: 1

OK
==================
Band3 (1800 MHz)
at+bmbandpref=2000000680380,4,3f


OK
at+bmtcellinfo
+BMTCELLINFO: CELL_ID:111925813,111925813,LAC_ID:65535,RSSI:68, RSRP:-100, RSRQ:-13, SINR:-22,active band:3,active channel:0,EARFCN_DL:0,EARFCN_UL:0

OK
at+bmband
+BMBAND: 3

OK
=================
Band7 (2600 MHz):
at+bmbandpref=2000000680380,40,3f


OK
at+bmtcellinfo
+BMTCELLINFO: CELL_ID:111925793,111925793,LAC_ID:65535,RSSI:72, RSRP:-109, RSRQ:-15, SINR:110,active band:7,active channel:0,EARFCN_DL:0,EARFCN_UL:0

OK
at+bmband
+BMBAND: 7

OK
================
Band8 (900 MHz):
at+bmbandpref=2000000680380,80,3f
ERROR
===============
Band20 (800 MHz):
at+bmbandpref=2000000680380,80000,3f


OK
at+bmtcellinfo
+BMTCELLINFO: CELL_ID:111925774,111925774,LAC_ID:65535,RSSI:54, RSRP:-85, RSRQ:-14, SINR:174,active band:20,active channel:0,EARFCN_DL:0,EARFCN_UL:0

OK
at+bmband
+BMBAND: 20

OK
===============
return default:
at+bmbandpref=2000000680380,80045,3f


OK
at+bmmodpref=0
+BMMODPREF: 0

OK

After installing firmware 2.1.4EU
https://ftp.dlink.de/dwm/dwm-222/driver_software/DWM-222_fw_reva1_214eu_win_multi_20210524.zip
this modem is managed by WebUI web browser. Here I cannot find a way to force these LTE bands, there is only LTE, 3G, 2G or Auto switching. Is there a possibility that in this WebUI also it would be possible to select individual LTE bands?

This modem DWM-222 HV ver. A1 is no longer supported by the manufacturer D-Link, there is still HW ver. A2 on sale .

@grawity_u1686, my mistake :)
